# ES6 Is it ok to use functions to make instances accessible to modules shared between many pages?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have 2 webpages, let's call them **A** and **B**.
They are mostly different but sometimes share some specific ES6 modules.
My directory structure is:

```
/A.js
/B.js
/A/main.js
/A/store.js
/B/main.js
/B/store.js
/commun/mymodule.js
```

`store.js` is a simple singleton object I use to easily share data across modules.

`mymodule` has the exact same logic in both `A` and `B` pages, the difference is the instance it uses is different. `mymodule` mainly contains **functions** and looks like this:

```
let objectFromAorB = null; // Will be the instance from A or B
let getItemStyle = null; // Will be a function set from A or B

const items = {}

function initItem(id) {
    // Fill item
    items[id] = [...];
}

function focusOnItem(id) {
    const item = items[id];
    // Do stuff with item
    // [...]
    objectFromAorB.refresh(); // HERE: objectFromAorB
}

function setItemVisible(id) {
    const item = items[id];
    // Do stuff with item
    // [...]
    item.setStyle(getItemStyle(id)); // HERE: getItemStyle
}

// HERE: Setters
function setObject(extObj) {
    objectFromAorB = extObj;
}
function setStyleFunction(fct) {
    getItemStyle = fct;
}

export { setObject, setStyleFunction, initItem, focusOnItem, setItemVisible };
```

In **main.js** from **A** and **B** I do things like this:

```
import Store from './store';
import * as Mymodule from '../commun/mymodule';

const anImportantObject = [...];
Mymodule.setObject(anImportantObject);
Mymodule.setStyleFunction(function(id) {
    const color = Store.element[id]?.color;
    return { color: color, [...] };
});
```

I have to share the `anImportantObject` instance from **A/main.js** or **B/main.js** to `common/mymodule.js`, and I also have to use a function to define how the style is obtained because the data comes either from **A/store.js** or **B/store.js**.

I'm struggling with this because I find it difficult to read, difficult to scale, and I am pretty sure there are a lot better ways to deal with this as it should be a common problem. But after a large look over the Internet I didn't find my solution.

Comment: At a glance, that looks mostly reasonable. Personally, I'd prefer to avoid reassignment and instead have `mymodule` either be a higher-order function or class which accepts the object and style function as arguments

Comment: @CertainPerformance After reading your comment I took a look at the higher-order function (because I didn't hear the term). Isn't what I am already doing here?

Comment: As in, a function that returns a function. Or, here, I guess it'd be a function that returns an object of functions. `export const makeItemInterface = (objectFromAorB, getItemStyle) => {
  const items = {};
  // ...
  return ({
    focusOnItem(id) {
      const item = items[id];
      objectFromAorB.refresh();
    }` or something along those lines